# Progress Drawable in a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a newbie to android development and am working on a project. I'm trying to add a circulaprogressdrawable in my fragment when the image is getting loaded. But its not loading at all. It used to work when I was not using Fragment and had the code inside an activity. Can someone please advise what am I doing incorrect? any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks. Following is the code for reference

```
package com.example.demoauthfirebase


import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.CircularProgressDrawable
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class FragmentImage : Fragment() {


    companion object {
        const val ARG_NAME = "urlVal"

        fun newInstance(urlVal: String): FragmentImage {
            val fragment = FragmentImage()

            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putString(ARG_NAME, urlVal)
            }

            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val activity = activity as Context

        var circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(activity)
        circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 10f
        circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 50f
        circularProgressDrawable.setColorSchemeColors(Color.GREEN)
        circularProgressDrawable.start()


        val view: View = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_fragment_image, container,
            false
        )

        val imgView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgView1)

        val urlVal = arguments?.getString(ARG_NAME)
        val options = RequestOptions().placeholder(circularProgressDrawable)
        options.fitCenter()

        Glide.with(activity)
            .load(urlVal)
            .apply(options)
            .override(1200, 3000)
            .into(imgView)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return view
    }


}
```

Comment: just to add to that - everything is working well except that the drawable is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

this one got fixed by myself. The imageview I was using did not have a width and height mentioned explicitly. When I added that, it started to show up. Don't know if thats the best answer but it seems to be working. Below is the code of the fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentImage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="255dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```